# Display Python Output in Sublime text

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

New to Python & Sublime

Problem:
I type 'print ("Hello world")

How do I get it to show me the output (Hello world), is it in a separate window? or...

I understand I can use the Python Console built in, but that's a command line, what about when I get to use a ton of code, how do I get the output?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you prefer running / viewing output from sublime or from the command line?

Comment: This question is specifically about displaying the output of the python code in the build results window. Super+Shift+B is the right answer. It is not a duplicate of the other question, but an extension of it.

Comment: @pheon - Agreed.  Another way is to go to `Tools--> Build Results --> Show Build Results`.

Answer (score 8):

Click on tools > build systems > select Python, then Build with using ctr+shif B and select python, and it ll work. Second time you can use the build command, ctr + B since python is now set as default

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

Alternatively, if you're on linux or mac, save the file as hello.py in your home directory and do the following in a terminal / command line:

```
$ cat hello.py
print("Hello World")
$ python3 hello.py
Hello World
```

If you're on Windows you're best off using the built-in functionality of sublime.

Answer (score 0):

My [Sublime Extras](https://github.com/Veedrac/Sublime-Extras) extension, and [MiniPy](https://github.com/vim/MiniPy), the extension I stole it from, both allow this. Search "eval" on the Extras Github page or use MiniPy.

Maybe [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), too, depending in what you are after.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP just wants to see the output, and not get the output automatically put into the file being edited.

Comment: Maybe. It's not especially clear to me.